# How can I remove the VS warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'SPREADSHEET' when no variable is declared

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, struct, typedef, warnings

This warning is triggered multiple times in my code by the same declaration, which reads :

```
// Spreadsheet structure
typedef struct SPREADSHEET
{    
      int ID;               // ID of the spreadsheet    
      UINT nLines;          // Number of lines

      void CopyFrom(const SPREADSHEET* src)
      {
           ID = src->ID;
           nLines = src->nLines;
      }
};
```

I don't want to just turn off that warning,

but rather change the code so that the warning doesn't come up !

NOTE : I don't want to declare any variables here (it's a header file), only define what the struct 'SPREADSHEET' should include...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Delete `typedef`. It's the C way of declaring structs, C++ does it automatically for you.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) In our case we had no `typedef` to begin with (`MSVC 2010`), but adding one with identifier before the terminating `;` did the trick (like `MY_EXPORT_MACRO typedef struct MY_TYPE { ... } MY_TYPE;`).

Answer (score 9):

**If you use same header for both C and C++**, you need to add some identifier before the terminating "`;`", something like:

```
typedef struct BLAH { ... } BLAH;
```

**But** if you use it only for C++, instead simply remove "`typedef` " part (and don't add identifier before the terminating "`;`", as without "`typedef` " part that creates a variable).

---

Also, you may want to edit C-only-headers and wrap everything in `extern "C" { ... }`, to support C++, like:

```c
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif // __cplusplus

// ... Content: Includes and Type-defs go here ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern C
#endif // __cplusplus

#endif // MY_HEADER_H
```

> I mean, else each C++ file which includes your C-only-header needs to wrap separately.

Comment: All previous MSVC were accepting `typedef enum { ... };` silently, maybe because it's in `extern "C" { ... }`, but since update to MSVC 2015 we get all these warnings.

Comment: Anyway, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove "`typedef`". You declare a new struct and the `typedef` keyword isn't used for that. You would use `typedef` to define a new name for an existing type, like this:

```
typedef int number;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `BLAH` *after* the closing brace is important to make the `typedef` a valid one. You can remove the `SPREADSHEET` from the present place and keep it in between the `}` and the `;`.

Comment: That should be left as a comment, please earn the required reputation by asking and answering question and review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of this warning is that the compiler is indicating that the `typedef` keyword is unnecessary because a variable is not being declared. and therefore if the intention of the code is to simply declare a `struct` the `typedef` is superfluous.